# R Markdown displaying just displaying the result

Tags: markdown, rstudio

I have been exploring with R Markdown and came across this question. All the reproducible example reports I found online such as this http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.ca/2012/05/example-reproducile-report-using-r.html has the code followed by the result.

I want to have just the result therefore hiding the code from the audience. For example, I would just like to display the end result of ggplot2 or googlevis without showing the long lines of loading data and coding.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 7):

Just add `echo = FALSE` to the code [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options).